# JavaScript false && false

Tags: javascript, boolean

I am doing the code academy javascript course. We are starting with the objects section and I came across this boolean expression:

!(false && (!false)) which evaluates to true.

To me this seems the same as: !(false && true); which evaluates to false.
This doesn't make sense to me, how is !(false && (!false)) true?
What am I missing here?

Comment: `!(false && true)` is not `false`

Comment: If something is not false then it is true, and if you combine that with the exact same condition then the ultimate result is true.

Answer (score 6):

`!(false && (!false))`

`!(false && true)`

`!(false)`

`true`

In math, you always do what's in the parenthesis first. The same concept can be used here. If you come across similar things again, evaluate it in steps.

Answer (score 2):

What you're missing is:

```
!(false && (!false))
3       2      1
```

1) !false = true

2) false && true = false

3) !(false) = true.

Therefore, the statement is TRUE. The key here is the first FALSE make the entire inner statement FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've explained the solution in your post itself. Anyway, as you've mentioned (false && true) evaluates to false, which is then inverted with the leading ! thus resulting in true.

Answer (score 0):

```
(false && true) == false
```

but after you have a **!** which convert your **false** result to a **true**